# player changing the reference in-game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

friends, when I wrote a script for a circle to rotate at a certain speed, we can normally change the speed from within unity, but I also want the player to change the speed just like we change the speed in unity, I searched and couldn't find it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a UI element such as a button, slider or inputfield, then connect the event to a method in your script to change the speed.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Slider.html

Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2vOeTK0z2g